# Derivative of convolution proof

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, convolution

Using the definition of convolution: $$ (f*g)(x) = \frac {1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x-t)g(t)dt$$ I need to prove the following:

Let $f$ be a continuously differentiable function. Then $f*g$ is also differentiable and it's derivative at point $t$ is $((f')*g)(t)$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Use the definition of derivative and swap the convolution integral with the $\lim$ in the definition of derivative.

Comment: I don't think I understand. What exactly do I need to swap? Do I use the definition of derivative on the convolution function? If I do that all I get is a limit that I can't really evaluate or calculate. Could you expand on your hint? Thanks!

Comment: First, by writing $${d\over dx}f*g(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}{f*g(x+h)-f*g(x)\over h}$$ and substituting $f*g$ from its definition, you will get to an integral enclosed by the $\lim$, that is$$\lim_{h\to 0}{f*g(x+h)-f*g(x)\over h}=\lim_{h\to 0}{\int [f(x+h-t)-f(x-t)]*g(t)dt\over h}$$Completing the proof requires $\int$ and $\lim$ to be swapped under certain conditions (which should be met carefully).